# Indesign type not working, shows up small and garbled

Tags: adobe-indesign, typesetting

i'm working on indesign and i'm fairly new but i am trying to type something and it shows up like this[image]

Comment: Check tracking, kerning, etc.. all the Character Panel (Window > Type & Tables > Character)

Comment: Do you have a very tiny text with *stroke* applied?

Comment: Yes, text with stroke for sure. BTW, why is this question closed? Are we not here to help? I'll never understand this closing topic politics... anyway...

Answer (score 1):

One's thing's for sure there's nothing wrong with your InDesign, but likely some type-related setting that brings characters on top of each other. Could be many possible reasons for this, so hard to give a clear answer. Look at:

- character stroke
- character kerning, tracking
- language settings
- try changing the font to Arial, the actual font file you're using may be broken

Ultimately, restore your default InDesign preferences:

- https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/setting-preferences.html